# Код сворачивается

Tags: html, visual-studio

Начинающий верстальщик, пользуюсь VS-code, иногда код всхлопывается, пробовал Shift + Alt + F, рекомендуемые плагины все стоят - ничего не работает, приходится корректировать вручную, что очень неудобно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложи сюда скрин нормально. По левым ссылкам ходить не хочется. Можно отредактировать ответ и там вставить изображение.

Comment: У вас минифицируется код, скорее всего стоит для этого какой то плагин, отключите его или разберитесь как он работает. Лично я для минификации не использую плагины VS Code, поэтому не в курсе как ими пользоваться

Comment: Извиняюсь, это мой первый вопрос. Наверное снесу все плагины и установлю лишь несколько самых используемых